# How to turn on/off Azure web apps during office hours

Tags: azure, automation, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I would like to shutdown my azure Web App over night and automate this.
I already set it up on my Azure Virtual Machines with a run book.

Problem with azure web apps: when you stop it, you're still being billed, the CI still works, the monitoring tools are still available etc. The only way to stop being billed is to downgrade the service plan to a free one when I don't need the app, and I do it manually.

My question is: did anyone manage to automate it? How?

Comment: thank you for that! 

well it does but partially, so from the answer to that question, one way is to automate the creation and destruction of a web app.. But it's so heavy!
And I'm using a symfony php app that needs to run a few commands to install it, create its cache, with extra php plugins, so it might be a pain to create it... 

Isn't there any way to simply automate the switching of the service plan?

Comment: I have modified the answer to that question with the command you'd need to change the service plan tier.

Comment: Awesome,  thank you Michael for that!